# multiple wdio.conf.js files and same hook repeated in both of them

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, wdio, wdio-v6

I am using javascript, nodejs, npm, wdio, cucumber in my testing automation framework.

In my main project root folder I have `wdio.conf.js` file. Suppose there is a dependency in `node_modules` folder with its own `wdio.conf.js` file. And suppose both wdio.conf.js has `afterScenario()` hook.

Two queries:

1)I want to ask which wdio.conf.js file will be run and which `afterScenario()` hook will be run?

2)Suppose I want to run `afterScenario()` hook in both `wdio.conf.js` files. How can I do this?

EDIT:

```
ROOT FOLDER:

|-some file

|-wdio.conf.js (contains afterScenario() hook)

|-package.json

|-nodes_module

       |-dependency1
    
             |-Some files
    
             |-package.json
      
             |-wdio.conf.js (also contains afterScenario() hook)
    
       |-dependency2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I completely understood your question. So let me ask you this, would having something like this in your package.json help?

```js
"scripts": {
  "test1": "wdio wdio.conf1.js",
  "test2": "wdio wdio.conf2.js"
}
```

Where in wdio.conf1.js you would have 1 afterScenario() hook and in the wdio.conf2.js you would have a different afterScenario() hook. So if you rename your local wdio configuration may be enough to fix your issue?
Let me know if this helps!

Comment: But in this way i will be able to run one wdio.conf.js at one time. For example, `>npm test1` will run only wdio.conf1.js. By the way I have edit my question. If you can please have a look at it.